React Native - Open Web Page in WebView after read QR Code
Im trying open a specific page in Web View after read a QR Code.
Normally the page is shown, but sometimes the page stay blank with the loading icon and never loads. I need to close the application and open it again.
Any help would be appreciated.
reader.js
const Reader = () => {

  const isQRCodeRead = useRef(false);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();

const handleBarcodeRead = (event) => {
  if (event.data && !isQRCodeRead.current) {
    console.log(event.data);
    isQRCodeRead.current = true;
    navigation.navigate('Page'); //is from @react-navigation/native
  }
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFocused) {
    isQRCodeRead.current = false;
  }
}, [isFocused]);

  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <RNCamera
        style={styles.camera}
        type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
        captureAudio={false}
        onBarCodeRead={handleBarcodeRead}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

page.js
const Page = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const webViewRef = useRef(null);

  //reload page
  const refreshPage = () => {
    if (webViewRef.current) {
      webViewRef.current.reload();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      refreshPage();
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <WebView
        ref={webViewRef}
        source={{ uri: 'https://mypage.com/register', cache: 'no-cache' }} 
      />
    </View>
  );
};


export default Page;

